Help running a file
I am sorry if this is a naive question, but I am wondering how I am supposed to run this file: https://github.com/brandizzi/input-device-indicator/?tab=readme-ov-file
it says "invoke input-device-indicator" but where and how can I do that?
I tried doing ./input-device-indicator
but, I don't think that is how it works.
Any ideas on how you can do that?

The application's author appears to maintain a PPA (personal package archive) ppa:brandizzi/ppa so you shouldn't need to manually build it from the github source. See also How to repair a PPA to not get "The repository is not signed.".
